# dual boot Windows xp and Windows 7 from the same partition

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, multi-boot

After installing Windows 7 (ver. Enterprise 64-bit) my old Windows XP installation has been moved to the "Windows.old" directory.

Now I know it is possible to restore and boot Windows XP again by moving it back to the root directory and updating the MBR as described [here](http://www.askthecomputertech.com/uninstall-windows-7.html).

Btw, is it possible to repeat the procedure multiple times, switching from one OS to another?
(eg. temporary move Windows 7 to "Windows.new" and restore it later)

2nd question:
Is it possible to automate the OS-switching procedure at boot-time?
(Basically i need a boot loader that is able to mount the NTFS partition and execute a script to move the files.)

Answer (score 0):

When you install Windows 7, do not install it into the Windows directory. Install it into a different directory. Doing this will preserve your Windows XP installation, and add a option to choose your OS at boot time.

When you install into the same directory, windows does an upgrade instead of a separate install.

Please note that doing this will consume the space of 2 separate windows installations on your hard drive.

Comment: i didn't notice such an option during the Win7 installation procedure, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: My apologies. I was never notified of your reply, so i thought this was resolved. Windows 7 setup should prompt you for the type of install you want. Choose custom (Or advanced) then it should give you the option of placing it somewhere else. At worst case, you may need to use a partition manager to resize your XP drive, and create a new partition to install windows 7